# Shared Preferences Not Working In Customview

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-custom-view

I'm trying to call `getSharedPreferences()` in a customview, which is located in a fragment. When calling the function I get a "cannot find symbol method" error.

I tried calling getActivity in the customview, but that doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getSharedPreferences()` is accessible by referencing the context.

You can try `<someview>.getContext().getSharedPreferences()`
or `getActivity.getSharedPreferences()`